Parcel "npm run build:js" changes app.js file and not bundle.js

I have a Node.js project and after the Parcel update I'm running into an issue.

In my ./public/js/ folder I have 2 files: bundle.js and bundle.js.map. Previously Parcel was compiling/ bundling the code in these 2 files. However, after the update it's now changing my app.js file. And I can't figure out how to adjust parcel to the before-mentioned 2 files.

My package.json looks like this.
{
  ...
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "watch:js": "parcel watch ./public/js/index.js --dist-dir ./public/js/bundle.js --no-source-maps",
    "build:js": "parcel build ./public/js/index.js --dist-dir ./public/js/bundle.js --no-source-maps"
  },
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "parcel": "^2.13.0",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  ...
  "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.5",
  ...
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.0.0"
  }
}

When I run "npm run watch:js" it adjusts the app.js, which is not in my ./public/js folder at all. See below the file and folder structure of my project.

Hopefully I've described the issue with sufficient background and info. If not, please let me know! I could not find another question concerning this issue.

Hope someone can help me with this issue.
